# Ignore or solve error "type must implement the inherited abstract method"

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

interface rateOfInterest {
    void ROI();
    void display();
}

class SBI implements rateOfInterest {
    public void ROI() {

        int p, t;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Principal amount");
        p = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the Time in years");
        t = in.nextInt();
        p = p * t;
        System.out.println("Enter the Simple Interest");
        float s = in.nextInt() * 100;
        s = s / p;
        float r = s;
        display(r);
    }

    public void display(float r) {
        System.out.println("The ROI of SBI is " + r);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rateOfInterest r = new SBI();
        r.ROI();
        r.display();
    }
}
```

This is my code and the output is

> Enter the Principal amount
> 10000
> Enter the Time in years
> 5
> Enter the Simple Interest
> 1254
> The ROI of SBI is 2.508

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
    The type SBI must implement the inherited abstract method rateOfInterest.display()

    at SBI.display(Bank.java:10)
    at Bank.main(Bank.java:40)
```

Comment: no, you can't ignore that, you must implement every abstract method of every abstract class/interface in the hierarchy above your class

Comment: `SBI` implements `rateOfInterest`, so you must implement every method of that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the interface.  Neither method takes an argument.

```
interface rateOfInterest {
    void ROI();
    void display();
}
```

Here is your class.

```
class SBI implements rateOfInterest {
 ...
    public void display(float r) { // argument is here but not required.
        System.out.println("The ROI of SBI is " + r);
    }
}
```

You have two choices.

- Keep your existing method and create an empty display method.

```
  @Override 
  public void display() {}
```

- Or correct your current method to use the interface version.

Note:  When overriding inherited methods, use the @Override annotation as I did above to ensure you are matching the signature.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because
`void display()` in `interface rateOfInterest`
and
`public void display(float r)` in `class SBI`
do not match.

### Method 1

You can change

```
void display();
```

to

```
void display(float r);
```

in `interface rateOfInterest`.

You should also remove

```
r.display();
```

from the `main()` method because `ROI()` calls `display(r)` at the end.

### Method 2

You can change

```
public void display(float r)
```

in `class SBI` to

```
public void display()
```

and make `r` a member variable of `class SBI`.